# Hosting an asp.net website in my computer

Tags: asp.net, iis

I have an app I am modifying for a client. The app is in `asp.net`. I have read that I can deploy the app in three ways:

- xCopy Deployment
- Precompiled Deployment
- Web Setup Project

I would like to go with `xCopy` method. I have not installed visual studio but  have SQL server installed.

Coming from a *PHP* background, is *IIS* just like *apache* where I can copy my files inside a directory in *IIS* and launch the app in a web browser or is there an extra step that required to be able to run the `asp.net` web app?

Comment: try this: http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/show/1247/how-to-host-aspnet-application-on-the-web-server-iis

Comment: To enable check this link: http://quehow.com/how-to-install-iis-on-windows-7/3189.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/deployment/visual-studio-web-deployment/deploying-to-iis) is a complete guide to:

- Install IIS in windows
- Install SQL Server Express
- Publish to IIS in Visual Studio
- Finally, test in the test environment

**Note:** There is no need to install IIS, just enable its some settings. And you have to install SQL Server and Visual Studio.

### Edit:

- Install IIS

  - Open *Control Panel*, *Programs and Features*, **Turn Windows features on or off**.
  - Make sure that **ASP.NET 4.5** is selected under *Internet Information Services* -> World Wide Web Services -> **Application Development Features**.
  - Set ASP.Net Framework from v2.0 to v4.0: Press <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> and type *"inetmgr"* hit enter.
  - In the Application Pools pane under connections, click *DefaultAppPool*, and then in the Actions pane click **Basic Settings**.
  - In the Edit Application Pool dialog box, change .NET Framework version to **.NET Framework v4.0.30319** and click OK.
- Install SQL Server Express

  - Download it from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29062) either x64 and x86 based.
  - After downloading SQL Server run the setup and click **New SQL Server stand-alone installation**. In the installation wizard accept the default settings.
- Publish to IIS in Visual Studio

  - Run Visual Studio as Administrator by <kbd>Right</kbd> - <kbd>Click</kbd> on VS icon.
  - <kbd>Right</kbd> - <kbd>Click</kbd> on your project select *Publish*, in **Publish Web** create new *Profile*.
  - In Connection tab enter *localhost* -> Service URL, *Default Web Site/yourProjectName* -> Site/application, *http://localhost/yourProjectName* -> Destination URL
  - In Settings tab check *Exclude files from the App_Data folder*.
  - enter *Remote connection string* that you have use to connect with SQL Server database.
  - Check *Update database* and click *Configure database updates* add sql script `Grant.sql` that you will run in SQL Server which is like:

```html
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT name FROM sys.server_principals WHERE name = 'IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool')
BEGIN
    CREATE LOGIN [IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool] 
      FROM WINDOWS WITH DEFAULT_DATABASE=[master], 
      DEFAULT_LANGUAGE=[us_english]
END
GO
CREATE USER [ContosoUniversityUser] 
  FOR LOGIN [IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool]
GO
EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_owner', 'yourProjectName'
GO
```

- Finally click on Publish.
- Test in Environment

  Check that your project files have exits in *wwwroot* folder at *C:\inetpub\wwwroot\yourProjectName*. Run your project *index.aspx* file and test it.